# Firebase show if child exists

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using **FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter** and I'am trying to show post for the following users so I have used these method blew but It show posts if the post id is available at the following users:

Here's my json:

```
"Following" : {
    "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" : { 
       "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1": true,
      //I need to show this UID posts only but,
      //When I add here post id it show the post 
      //Ex:"-KduqnVVczZf5uibQiZ-" : true,//Post Shows Up
  },
  "Posts" : {
    "-KduqnVVczZf5uibQiZ-" : {
      "Describe" : "gg",
      "Time" : 14881230655,
      "UID" : "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
      "Username" : "Jone",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped906285501.jpg?alt=media&token=0c1a3a3d-6e48-4c4e-ba59-f5646bf8965f"
    },
    "-Ke5gJ00CxbjhOuhzLIx" : {
      "Describe" : "hajj",
      "Time" : 1488318465,
      "UID" : "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
      "Username" : "Dom",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1717103943.jpg?alt=media&token=a85b2488-5ac7-49a7-9ad0-dbf4e6f29389"
    },
    "-KeCuiFmUCpN19zwsTsR" : {
      "Describe" : "a",
      "Profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-suB77riNoX8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ADPlhfKMzINn-Ki538Sqf6SRGaXC81-WuQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Time" : 1488439652,
      "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2",
      "Username" : "Dom",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1913886685.jpg?alt=media&token=c8ad26b2-8f09-453b-b48a-aad9e4d8b5c3"
    },
    "-KeD2fBUQ09HVMrvAneb" : {
      "Describe" : "ee",
      "Profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-suB77riNoX8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ADPlhfKMzINn-Ki538Sqf6SRGaXC81-WuQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Time" : 1488441999,
      "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2",
      "Username" : "Dom",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1904338270.jpg?alt=media&token=d200b7fc-15e7-4dc4-9913-59c377929e9e"
    },
    "-KeDfnMWiB7k_4J3FBgZ" : {
      "Describe" : "f12g",
      "Time" : 1488452517,
      "UID" : "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" 
      "Username" : "Young",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1872832638.jpg?alt=media&token=80239844-a872-47e2-9689-92d368dd9452"
    },
    "-KeDfrw4inUQFtIDXJHp" : {
      "Describe" : "fg",
      "Time" : 1488452536,
      "UID" : "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" 
      "Username" : "Young",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1872832638.jpg?alt=media&token=80239844-a872-47e2-9689-92d368dd9452"
    },

  }
}
```

And here's my method that I use:

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
    mDatabaseFriends = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Following").child(mCurrentUser.getUid());

   FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts,PostViewHolder> firebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder>(
            Getting_Posts.class,R.layout.post_card_design,PostViewHolder.class,mDatabaseFriends,mDatabase)
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Getting_Posts model, int position) {}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a fiven reference have childrens you should use `dataSnapshot.exists()` or `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0` with the given `DataSnapshot` on your callback.

If you want to retrieve the post which `id` is equal to the followers you should modify your database adding an extra level to pur `Posts` table where the post will be already together based on a user id:

```
"Posts": {
"USER_ID_1": {
  "post_id_1": {
    "Describe": "gg",
    "Time": 14881230655,
    "UID": "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
    "Username": "Jone"
  },
  "post_id_2": {
    "Describe": "gg",
    "Time": 14881230655,
    "UID": "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
    "Username": "Jone"
  }
},
"USER_ID_2": {
  "post_id_3": {
    "Describe": "gg",
    "Time": 14881230655,
    "UID": "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
    "Username": "Jone"
  },
  "post_id_4": {
    "Describe": "gg",
    "Time": 14881230655,
    "UID": "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
    "Username": "Jone"
  }
}
```

To iterate looking to get all the posts inside each of your user's(just if you are following the new data model that I post you upside), you can retrieve them doing this:

```
        List<Getting_Posts> totalPosts = new ArrayList<>();
        //Check if the dataSnapshot have childrens
        if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
           //This for iterate for each USER_ID from your database
           for (DataSnapshot users : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              //This second iterate for each post for each user
              for (DataSnapshot posts : users.getChildren()) {
                 totalPosts.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Getting_Posts.class));
              }
           }
        }

        return totalPosts;
```

You can read more about this in the next post or in the oficial documentation:
https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data?hl=en-419

Comment: I know that but, Can you solve my problem by telling me how can I view the posts if it has equals uids to following users like the ex in the top, I need to show posts for the this uid:"pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1" because I have worked for 3 weeks trying to solve it but I couldn't so I say that I would have a chance whit asking may I have a perfect answer

Comment: check it again, i just modified my post

Comment: I got it brother but the problem that I also need to view all post. whats the  query that can be used to show all post. So do you have any idea for showing all posts together.

Comment: Firstly thanks for all your helping but I am still a beginner with firebase so can you please give me the completely answer to show all post and I am sorry if I disturbance you but I need the answer for finish my app and so this is the last thing that I have to upload my app so please I know that I'am taking from your time but help me please.

Comment: Cant I use the FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter or FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Comment: I can't make all your code mate. I edited again the answer to add you the way that i told you before to retrieve all the posts iterating through all of them. As I said, it's just 2 `for` over the same `DataSnapshot`(each one, go one level deeper in the tree).

To get more info you should study more about Firebase, I know that is boring, but is quite new and the only way to learn is coding it by yourself and fixing the problems. Remember to flag the useful comments.

Comment: Then you should change your `Getting_Posts` class to a new one called `User_posts` which will contain a `Hashmap<String, Getting_Post>`. Which means that each user_post item will contain a list of `PostID's` associated to your item.

Comment: Anyway thanks brother for trying to help me and I will take with you advice brother.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137677/discussion-between-francisco-durdin-garcia-and-7uthaifah).