# How to show the value after push Firebase android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on my final project, i got confused about how to show the value (expenses) from my firebase because I am using push,

[So this is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlpSI.png)

and here is my code to add it on database

```
    DatabaseReference itemsRef = mRef.child("Users/" + 
    mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).push();
    itemsRef.child("expenses").setValue(total);

    EditText itemedit = findViewById(R.id.macam1);
    macam1 = itemedit.getText().toString();
    itemsRef.child("items/").setValue(macam1 + ": " + item01);

    EditText itemedit2 = findViewById(R.id.macam2);
    macam2 = itemedit2.getText().toString();
    itemsRef.child("items2/").setValue(macam2 + ": " + item02);
```

my User.class

```
public class User {
    private  String name;
    private int balance,expenses;

    public  User(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }


    public void setExpenses(int expenses) {
        this.expenses = expenses;
    }

    public int getExpenses() {
        return expenses;
    }

}
```

this is the code so far:

```
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
final String key =  mRef.push().getKey();
String userid=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid).child(key);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            int expense = (int) dataSnapshot.child("expenses").getValue();
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalExpense);
            view.setText("" + expense);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

the `ref` already gave the value of the randomid but still error on
`int expense = (int) dataSnapshot.child("expenses").getValue();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase show if child exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699854/firebase-show-if-child-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve expenses from the database, try the following:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userid=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
  String expenses=datas.child("expenses").getValue().toString();

  }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

  }
});
```

In your database, you have `Users/userid/randomid/key:value`. So let the datasnapshot be at the `userid` then loop inside the randomid to be able to retrieve the child `expenses`

Comment: Hello @peter, I tried it then it goes to null reference, sorry, I am forgot to mention I had User class then i add it into 'expenses=datas.child("expenses").getValue(User.class).getExpenses;' and it shows 'Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type myapplication.User'. Sorry for long comment, I already include user.class on my question.

Comment: dont use user class, just use it as in the answer

Comment: If you want to use the user's class then remove the for loop `for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){` and do `User user=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);`

Comment: i tried without using user.class (as u suggest) it gave me 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference'

Comment: what is userid returning?

Comment: it's return the id: ZsJPie1JUGQBR5tpCw0qZNnZ4lQ2(correct),
and the error is at String expenses=datas.child("expenses").getValue().toString();

Comment: it gave 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer'
and also it is said that randomid had no setter/field ('W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -LASvfCy7Xcw0-oXg-9Z').

Sorry man, too many questions :)

Comment: Try and retrieve items `String items=dataSnapshot.child("items").getValue().toString();` Also why did u add child(key) just loop inside of it